# GDI+: Grayscale PNG loaded as PixelFormat32bppARGB

Tags: c++, windows, gdi+

I am trying to load a grayscale PNG file using GDI+ on Windows 7/64bits Pro. However if I use the value returned from [Image::GetPixelFormat()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms535387(v=vs.85).aspx), it tells me that the pixelFormat is `PixelFormat32bppARGB`.

If I convert this PNG to JPG and/or TIFF it now tells me that the pixelFormat is now `PixelFormat8bppIndexed`.

Looking at the definition for thoses values [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms534412(v=vs.85).aspx), does not tell much. However looking them [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa921023.aspx), reveals that `PixelFormat32bppARGB` is in fact the result of `(10 | (32 << 8) | PixelFormatAlpha | PixelFormatGDI | PixelFormatCanonical)`.

My questions are:

1. What does the following means: `PixelFormatCanonical: Is in canonical format` ?
2. I understand that GDI+ is free to represent single component grayscale image as 32bpp ARGB, non-premultiplied alpha, but then how do I check that the underlying representation is actually grayscale ? This will prove useful since I only want to copy a single componentent from the ARGB buffer.

Here are some information from the PNG file using the `pnginfo` command from a UNIX shell:

```
$ pnginfo input.png
input.png...
  Image Width: 2492 Image Length: 3508
  Bitdepth (Bits/Sample): 8
  Channels (Samples/Pixel): 1
  Pixel depth (Pixel Depth): 8
  Colour Type (Photometric Interpretation): GRAYSCALE 
  Image filter: Single row per byte filter 
  Interlacing: No interlacing 
  Compression Scheme: Deflate method 8, 32k window
  Resolution: 11811, 11811 (pixels per meter)
  FillOrder: msb-to-lsb
  Byte Order: Network (Big Endian)
  Number of text strings: 0 of 0
```

This is even an issue with `wine` implementation of GDI+. Current [wine 1.6.2](https://bugs.winehq.org/show_bug.cgi?id=38622) also think my input PNG really is: `PixelFormat8bppIndexed`.

Comment: Your assumption that GetPixelFormat() tells you anything about the file format is just wrong.  It tells you what the image codec chose for the in-memory representation of the bitmap data.  That will never be one of the grayscale formats, it isn't compatible with your hardware.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After trying all possible functions from the GDI+ Image class, I think found the solution. One need to retrieve the [flags](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms535376(v=vs.85).aspx) from the Image and test against [ImageFlagsColorSpaceGRAY](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms534136(v=vs.85).aspx)

For Grayscale PNG:

- PixelFormat is: `PixelFormat32bppARGB`
- `ImageFlagsColorSpaceGRAY` is set (`ImageFlagsColorSpaceRGB` is **not** set)

For RGB PNG:

- PixelFormat is: `PixelFormat24bppRGB`
- `ImageFlagsColorSpaceRGB` is set (`ImageFlagsColorSpaceGRAY` is **not** set)

For RGBA PNG:

- PixelFormat is: `PixelFormat32bppARGB`
- `ImageFlagsColorSpaceRGB` is set (`ImageFlagsColorSpaceGRAY` is **not** set)

Answer (score 0):

1: The page you linked for the flags is a page from Windows CE, did you confirm that the flags in your Windows SDK are actually the same?

2: The Image::GetPixelFormat tells you the pixel format of the Image object, which does not have to be the same as the PNG file.

At the bottom of the page [describing the pixel formats](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms534412(v=vs.85).aspx) there is a remark:

> PixelFormat48bppRGB, PixelFormat64bppARGB, and PixelFormat64bppPARGB use 16 bits per color component (channel). Windows GDI+ version 1.0 can read 16-bits-per-channel images, but such images are converted to an 8-bits-per-channel format for processing, displaying, and saving.